# XAMPP and .htaccess authentication on Windows 2008 R2 - Missing AccessFileName

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have XAMPP successfully installed and running on my Windows 2008 R2 server. Apache is running fine. I would like to password protect a specific directory using Apache basic authentication. I have looked at various articles covering .htaccess when using XAMPP but they mention a directive that is missing in my `httpd.conf` file.

`AccessFileName`

If this entry is not present in the `httpd.conf` file should I just go ahead and add it?

Here is some other info regarding my setup:

1. mod-rewrite is enabled - `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
2. IIS is NOT enabled

Comment: Thanks @Prix. I am not sure why bt my httpd.conf did not have `AccessFileName`. I went ahead and added it and all worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be somewhere in your `httpd.conf` something like this, if you don't try adding it.

```
#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

You should also have this one:

```
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
```

It's very odd that you have it missing as it is something default.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xampp v3.2.4 and I also didn't find **AccessFileName** in **httpd.conf**.
I have searched this text inside conf/extra directory.
and found **AccessFileName** in `conf/extra/httpd-default.conf`

This file `httpd-default.conf` is included in the `httpd.conf` file.
Find  `Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"` in httpd.conf.

So you don't need to add it manually. Just try changing there and be sure that `Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"` is not commented by `#`.